# Resizing wallpaper after reboot

Tags: android, launcher, wallpaper, android-launcher, android-wallpaper

I build my custom launcher for Android 4.4.2 and have some problem with wallpapers. When I set new wallpaper everything is good image fit to screen, but after reloading device, wallpaper gets scaled and I see the only center part, even if screen size and image size identical by default. 
I think this is because of multiple screens mode, but I'm not sure. Right now I reset wallpaper every time with Broadcast Receiver on ACTION_BOOT event, but it provides some lags and doesn't look like an elegant solution.
I set and reload wallpaper with this class:

```
public class WallpaperUtils {

public static final String PREF_CUSTOM_WALLPAPER = "PREF_CUSTOM_WALLPAPER";
public static final String PREF_WALLPAPER_RES = "PREF_WALLPAPER_RES";

public static void reloadWallpaper(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    boolean isCustomWallpaper = prefs.getBoolean(PREF_CUSTOM_WALLPAPER, false);

    if (isCustomWallpaper) {
        int wallRes = prefs.getInt(PREF_WALLPAPER_RES, 0);
        setWallpaper(context, wallRes);
    }


}

public static void setWallpaper(Context context, int wallRes) {

    WallpaperManager manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext());

    WindowManager window = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    window.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    Bitmap tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), wallRes);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempBitmap, width, height, true);

    manager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
    manager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);

    try {
        manager.setBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

and in AndroidManifest home screen looks like:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In default launcher wallpaper scales too, so I don't think that problem with style, but I can't find where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After researching about android themes and styles I'll understand what's going wrong.

> @android:style/Theme

is deprecated and don't recommend to use after API 11.

So I just get the wallpaper in home screen activity in an onStart callback via wallpaper manager and set as background to the main layout.